# How do I determine the internal HWND used by COM in my current process?

Tags: c, winapi, com, hwnd, sta

I want to Post messages directly to the HWND that's owned by COM in my process.  How do I get the HWND that COM is using in single-threaded-apartment mode?

Comment: What would be the use case for this? I can't help but think, that this is a terrible hack, likely the result of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: It's a terrible hack.  You're right.   That isn't illegal.  Is it?

Comment: It is legal. It is also legal to juggle chainsaws.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I agree with you 100%.   But what do I do about this?   I want to capture this information on stackoverflow so that I, or others, can get back to it at some other time in the future.

Comment: Again, what would be the use case for this? Why don't you ask about the real problem you are trying to solve instead of your proposed solution?

Comment: @zumalifeguard I tried to do this sort of thing (and was successful) many years ago, but I found better solutions to every problem for which I have ever considered this. If you would like to discuss, here or privately, your use case, I would be happy to offer some alternatives for you to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
HWND prevWindow = NULL;
HWND hwnd;
for ( ;; )
{
    hwnd = FindWindowEx( HWND_MESSAGE, prevWindow, L"OleMainThreadWndClass", NULL );
    if ( !hwnd )
        break;

    if ( GetWindowThreadProcessId( hwnd, NULL ) == GetCurrentThreadId() )
        break;

    prevWindow = hwnd;


    WCHAR className[255];
    *className = 0;
    ::GetClassName( hwnd, className, 255 );
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: You're asking yourself to tell if that works? Wow :D

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow should answer the question being asked. If you need to ask, whether a proposed solution is correct or not, you need to put that in your question. Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45385193/edit) link and update your question.

Comment: Okay, IInspectable.   I'll do that.

Comment: Wait.   I'm not asking if a proposed solution is correct or not in the question.  The question is simply asking how to do it.